# Cypress test: Writing multiple elements to database failed

Tags: cypress

Trying to write multiple elements into database failed, only the last one is written:

```
// my_test.cy.js
import CreateProductPage from "../pages/CreateProductPage";

describe('product detail page', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login('admin', 'shop')
    })

    it('should print typed product', () => {
        cy.createProduct(null, 'Component Product 0', '0')
        CreateProductPage.elements.productDetailTabs().should('exist') // <--- to detect that the entity is written
        cy.createProduct('combinable', 'Combined Test Product', '0')
        CreateProductPage.elements.productDetailTabs().should('exist') // <--- to detect that the entity is written
    })
})

// commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('createProduct', (type, name, grossPrice) => {
    cy.visit('/#/sw/product/create')
    CreateProductPage.elements.productDetailTabs().should('not.exist').then(() => {
        if(type === 'combinable') {
            CreateProductPage.elements.radioBtnCombinableProduct().click()
        }
        CreateProductPage.elements.inputProductName().clear().type(name)
        CreateProductPage.elements.inputPriceFieldGross().type(grossPrice)
        SwPageHeader.elements.btnProductSave().click()
    })
})
```

Questions:

- This failed because of [asynchronous nature of cypress](https://learn.cypress.io/cypress-fundamentals/understanding-the-asynchronous-nature-of-cypress)?
- If so, how to interrupt? Chaining with `then()`, the behavior is the same

With this is code (adding `wait()`) it works, but **i'm looking for the right way**

```
// my_test.cy.js
describe('product detail page', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.login('admin', 'shop')
    })

    it('should print typed product', () => {
        cy.createProduct(null, 'Component Product 0', '0')
        CreateProductPage.elements.productDetailTabs().should('exist')
        cy.wait(300)        
        cy.createProduct('combinable', 'Combined Test Product', '0')
        CreateProductPage.elements.productDetailTabs().should('exist')
    })
})
```

**EDIT 1**

```
// pages/CreateProductPage.js

class CreateProductPage {
    elements = {
        productDetailTabs: () => cy.get('div.sw-product-detail-page__tabs'),
        radioBtnCombinableProduct: () => cy.get('.sw-product-detail-base__info input#type_combinable_product-0'),
        radioBtnUnCombinableProduct: () => cy.get('.sw-product-detail-base__info input#type_combinable_product-1'),
        inputProductName: () => cy.get('input#sw-field--product-name'),
        inputPriceFieldGross: () => cy.get('div.sw-list-price-field__price input#sw-price-field-gross'),
    }
}

module.exports = new CreateProductPage();
```

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint the problem without seeing the `CreateProductPage` code

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is one of waiting, you will need to figure out something that indicates ***to the user*** that the save was successful and test that.

For example, if there was a toast message on screen:

```js
...
SwPageHeader.elements.btnProductSave().click()
cy.contains('span', 'Product was saved').should('be.visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> This failed because of asynchronous nature of cypress?

Code behaves synchronously if you have only cy commands inside the code block.

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74721728/9088832 you should wait for some element to appear or for an API request to be completed that is responsible for the product creation.

Comment: @Paolo,  this is done by `CreateProductPage.elements.productDetailTabs().should('exist') // <--- to detect that the entity is written` This element appears only after successfully upload (response is 200)